# arrows on a path of integration

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a clockwise arrow on the smaller circle and a counterclockwise arrow on the larger one

```
    \begin{figure}[H]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick,decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}},
     mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}}
     ]
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,0) circle (0.5);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0.33,0.33) node[midway,right,rotate=-45] 
    {$\rho \rightarrow0$};
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (-1.05,1.05) node[midway,right,rotate=45] 
    {$\rho' \rightarrow\infty$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
   \caption{contour for gamma function}
   \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{stealth}},
     mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}}] (0.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
     markings, mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrowreversed{stealth}}}] (0,0) circle (1.5);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
     markings, mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow{stealth}}}] (0,0) circle (0.5);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0.33,0.33) node[midway,right,rotate=-45] 
    {$\rho \rightarrow0$};
   \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (-1.05,1.05) node[midway,right,rotate=45] 
    {$\rho' \rightarrow\infty$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I were to make this graph, I'd make it larger and do some other minor improvements.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% Arrows library for...
\usetikzlibrary{bending}% The bending library is the one that allows the bending of the arrows
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing} % braces
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
    \draw[thick] (-2,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0.5,0) -- (2,0);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Latex[length=0.3cm]}}}] (0.5,-0.1) --
     (1.5,-0.1);
    \draw[ultra thick, postaction={decorate},decoration={
     markings,
     mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrowreversed{Latex[length=0.3cm]}}}]
     (0.5,0.1) -- (1.5,0.1);
    \draw[ultra thick] (4:1.5) arc(4:356:1.5cm);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{Latex[length=0.3cm,bend]}] (270:1.5) arc(270:225:1.5cm);
    \draw[ultra thick] (10:0.5) arc(10:350:0.5cm);
    \draw[ultra thick,-{Latex[length=0.3cm,bend]}] (180:0.5) arc(180:225:0.5cm);
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},gray] (0,0) -- (-45:0.5)
    node[midway,below,sloped] {$\rho \rightarrow0$};
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror},gray] (0,0) -- (135:1.5)
    node[midway,sloped,above]{$\rho' \rightarrow\infty$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice... +1.